# Airflow Installation Issues

Tags: airflow

I have freshly installed airflow. I am getting this error when I am running webserver.

```
[2021-03-11 02:19:26,889] {dagbag.py:448} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /dev/null
[2021-03-11 02:19:27,040] {manager.py:727} WARNING - No user yet created, use flask fab command to do it.
```

1. 

Why is DagBag being filled form /dev/null? I have correct location in .cfg file. What can I do/improve?

2. No user yet created, use flask fab command to do ? Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

1 Did you setup `AIRFLOW_HOME`? The default value for `dags_folder` is `{AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags`

2 User isn't created by default. You will need to create a user to login.

```
create an admin user
airflow users create \
    --username admin \
    --firstname Peter \
    --lastname Parker \
    --role Admin \
    --email spiderman@superhero.org
```

You can read more about this is the [documentation](http://%20https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/webserver.html#web-authentication).

Comment: on 1, I did export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow. Is that all?

Comment: If the value of dags bag is set correctly in airflow.cfg you might want to restart airflow and check if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error  web server not starting.
When connecting postgresSQL, because the resource of docker ran out of memory to run airflow. So I solved it by increasing the memory to 4GB.

- Preferences...> Resources > Memory : 4GB